# Show that $\exists \xi : f'(\xi) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:**

> Let $f: [0,\infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be continous on the interval $[0,\infty)$, and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Also, $f(0) = 0, \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$. Show there $\exists \xi > 0 : f'(\xi) = 0$

**My attempt:**

Take an arbitrary $x > 0$. Since $f$ is continous and differentiable on the given interval, we can use the Integral Mean Value Theorem. In other terms, there $\exists \xi \in (0,x)$ such that:

$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(\xi)$

Since $f(0) = 0$, we have:

$\frac{f(x)}{x} = f'(\xi)$

Taking the limit of both sides as $x$ tends to infinity, we get:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(\xi)$

Notice, since $f(x)$ is continous on $[0,\infty)$, it's bounded above by some real number $N$. Hence, the quotient $f(x) / x$ as $x$ tends to infinity, is just $"N/\infty"$, which tends to $0$. And so, in order for the equality above to hold, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi$.

Since $\xi \in (0,x)$, we have that $\xi$ is now in the interval $(0,\infty)$.

In other words, we have proven the statement.

$\square$

---

I hope you can give me some feedback on my solution. Whatever it might be that may be a wrong move.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you still need to prove that $\xi$ does not tend to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: The problem is that $\zeta$ depends on $x$ so you can’t simply take limits at both sides.

Comment: You correctly prove that $\forall x\, \exists \xi\quad f(x)/x = f'(\xi)$. In other words, $\xi$ depends on $x$. But you do not show that there is some fixed $\xi$ with $f'(\xi) = 0$. You also say "since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$, it's bounded above" - this is *extremely* false. It's true that your $f$ is bounded, but that's only because the limit exists. Your final deduction, where you take $x \to \infty$ and then later say $\xi \in (0,x)$, is literally meaningless.

Comment: It is not possible that $\xi\in(0,x)$ for arbitrary $x\gt0$, because this would imply that $f'(x)=0$ everywhere, which is to say, $f'$ is the $0$ function. It would be more accurate to say that for every $x$, there exists some $\xi(x)$ such that $f(x)/x = f'(\xi(x))$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu How would one prove that?

Comment: @preferred_anon I understand what you mean. Thank you. So, in order to say that the function is bounded, we have to state that, apart from it being continous, that limit as x tends to infinity exists, is what together makes it bounded.

Comment: @Angel Thank you for your comment. It seems like most of the comments agree on that I somehow have to show that $\xi$ is fixed, and that's what I suppose you mean too.

Comment: @Tanamas You need to prove that as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\xi(x)$ converges to some real number $\xi$. You have not proven this, which is why people are saying your $\xi$ is not fixed. This is important, because even if $\xi(x)$ does not converge and it diverges to $\infty$, $f(\xi(x))$ will still converge to $0$, since $f(x)$ converges to $0$. So having $f(x)/x=f'(\xi(x))$ and then evaluating the limit is not sufficient.

Comment: There is a much easier proof. If $f \neq 0$ there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = c \neq 0$. Since $f(0) = 0$ by the continuity of $f$ there must exist $x_1 < x_0$ such that $f(x_1) = c/2$. Since $f \to 0$ when $x \to \infty$ there also exists $x_2 > x_0$ such that $f(x) = c/2$. Then you just have to use Rolle's theorem with the points $x_1$, $x_2$.

Comment: @Angel Yes, I understand where it went wrong now. Thank you, it's more clear now as to why that's important to prove. However, how would one go on to do such a thing? I've worked with problems like these but never really had to prove convergence of $\xi$ in this way. Do you have any ideas / hints?

Comment: @Zanzag Thank you, that's actually alot easier than the proof I went on to show.

Comment: @Tanamas I am not sure how one would go about showing that. In fact, part of the reason I clicked on this question is because I had some curiosity as to what the proof was about. I am sorry I could not help any further.

Comment: @Angel, no problem. I appreciate your help. I certainly learned something, and that's what's important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\equiv0$ then we have nothing to do.

Suppose, without loss of generality, that there is $x_{0}$ in $(0,+\infty)$ such that $f(x_{0})=\delta>0$. By hypothesis $f$ is a continuous function and $f(0)=0=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)$, then by Intermediate Value Theorem, there is $0<x_{1}<x_{0}<x_{2},$ such that, $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})=\delta/2$, thereby, for Mean Value Theorem there is a $\xi$ in $(x_{1},x_{2})$ such that,
\begin{eqnarray}
f^{\prime}(\xi)=\frac{f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})}{x_{2}-x_{1}}=0.
\end{eqnarray}